# kohana db exception [0]

Tags: php, mysql, database, kohana

I have a big problem with connecting to mysql database. I tried everything and nothing worked.
If i try to connect on localhost with xampp to db on kohana (3.1.2), i get this error:

**Database_Exception [ 0 ]: ~ MODPATH\database\classes\kohana\database\mysql.php [ 67 ]**

but if i try run it on some server, it runs there and i dont know why, because everything is same (except db user and password).
I thought that it can be with mysql config, but i dont know what there.

Comment: Its hardly mysterious if you put that error in [Favourite Search Engine Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this problem and figured out what it was so even though this question is old, people having this problem should know the answer.

Basically when you get this error its because your using a version of php 5.5+.

`mysql_connect(...)` is a depreciated function starting in php 5.5 and above so the call in the framework is wrapped around a try/catch but the output from the catch doesn't give you any details about the error for whatever reason but if you remove the try/catch you'll see the real php error is simple saying mysql_connect is depreciated and will be removed in the future and to use mysqli instead.

To fix this open `index.php` in your root and basically you need to change the `error_reporting(...)` call to tell it not to error on depreciation errors which you can do like so to report all errors except warnings and deprecations.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_WARNING | E_DEPRECATED));
```

Another fix is to change your database config file to connect via PDO instead of mysql.

Comment: Thanks, @jeffwilbert

Answer (score 0):

I checked in Kohana 3.2, and there it means it can't connect to your database and throws an exception on that. But just go to the line 67 of the mysql.php file and check if the exception is triggered just after trying to connect to the DB.

Check your credentials in database config and make sure your MySQL server is up and running.